# How to retrieve the service fee details from Amazon market API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

Is it possible to retrieve the service fee charges independent of the SKU like Subscription Fee, FBA Inventory Storage Fee etc. using amazon market API.

I tried the [Financial Event API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/finances/Finances_ListFinancialEvents.html)  which returns the service fees in the format

```
<ServiceFeeEvent>
          <FeeList>
            <FeeComponent>
              <FeeType>FBADisposalFee</FeeType>
              <FeeAmount>
                <CurrencyAmount>-0.15</CurrencyAmount>
                <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              </FeeAmount>
            </FeeComponent>
          </FeeList>
        </ServiceFeeEvent>
```

Which does not contains the data like **PostedDate**. Is there any oter APIs availabile to get the detailed data of service fee amounts?

Comment: Hi Ajmal, I'm facing the same problem.  Did you find a solution?  The dates are in their TXT and XML files on the [Reports|Payments|All Statements] page on Seller Central.  But I don't know of any way to automate downloading those files.

Comment: Hi @EllisWhitehead, Unfortunately I cant find a proper solution. Somewhere in the amazon community forum found no such api exists. So we called the Financial event api in daily routine and assumes the Event date is same as api called date.

Answer (score 3):

In case it's useful for someone else, I figured out an approach that kind of works for me, though it's not ideal.
I'm using the Reports API to download the `_GET_V2_SETTLEMENT_REPORT_DATA_FLAT_FILE_` report, which has the fees **and** a `posted-date` column.  Some of Amazon's documentation about it can be found here: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html

The disadvantage is that it's only generated once every two weeks.  The advantage, compared to the Finances API, is that you get the posting date and the specific transaction that the fee came from.

Comment: Hi Ellis, still how would you go on with older data?

Comment: Hey ibrahimijc, I haven't been using this data for quite a while now, so I'm not familiar with it anymore.